# Wordpress - Echo within wp_list_authors + CIMY Extra User Fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to pull a list of all admins and contributors on my WordPress Website:

```
<?php wp_list_authors('hide_empty=0&exclude_admin=0'); ?>
```

This displays a list of all the authors, linked to their individual author pages.   I am using CIMY User Extra fields to allow my users to add lots of other information in their profiles, including an Avatar, so I'd like to also display the avatar for each author next to their name.  The image should also be linked, the same as their name, to their author page.

There is alot of documentation about how to pull various information from CIMY on this page: http://www.marcocimmino.net/cimy-wordpress-plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/documentation/

However I have not been able to use any of the information do to what I need.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do a foreach loop, for example something like that:

```
 <?php   $authors = wp_list_authors('hide_empty=0&exclude_admin=0'); 
        foreach ($authors as $author){
            $value = cimy_uef_sanitize_content(get_cimyFieldValue($author->ID,'IMAGE'));
            echo $value;
        } ?>
```

*I dont know if this will actually work, but it should be something similar to that.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Like I said I wasn't sure it would work, waht you should do is this: print_r($author); (in the foreach loop) then look for id, (it should be ID or term_id or something.

Comment: I just tried something like this but am not having much luck.  If you have a specific code example I could try, it would be great.

Comment: Ok, the problem is wp_list_author. We have to write a function, I'm working on it

Comment: function get_authors() {
 global $wpdb;
 $order = 'user_nicename';
 $user_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY $order");

 foreach($user_ids as $user_id) :
  $user = get_userdata($user_id);
  $all_authors[$user_id] = $user->display_name;
 endforeach;
 return $all_authors;
}
add this to your functions.php file

and replace wp_list_authors by get_authors()